# create sql query based flow filter

Tags: sql, sql-server, microsoft-dynamics, navision

I'm trying to create the sql query code based on a flow filter calc formula

So I have the table "Vendor Ledger Entry" with two important fields called "Amount" and "Remaining Amount".

Both fields are flowfiltes, calculated based on formulas with other tables (in this case Detailed Vendor Ledger Entry

Remaining Amount: `"Sum("Detailed Vendor Ledg. Entry".Amount WHERE (Vendor Ledger Entry No.=FIELD(Entry No.),Posting Date=FIELD(Date Filter),Excluded from calculation=CONST(No)))"`

So I "convert" the "Remaining Amount" to this sql query

```
   Select Sum([E18375$Detailed Vendor Ledg_ Entry].[Amount]) as 'Valor pendente'
    FROM [E18375$Detailed Vendor Ledg_ Entry]
    INNER JOIN [E18375$Vendor Ledger Entry] 
ON [E18375$Detailed Vendor Ledg_ Entry].[Vendor Ledger Entry No_] = [E18375$Vendor Ledger Entry].[Entry No_]
    WHERE [E18375$Detailed Vendor Ledg_ Entry].[Excluded from calculation] = 0 
AND [E18375$Detailed Vendor Ledg_ Entry].[Document No_]='1707NC006' 
AND YEAR([E18375$Detailed Vendor Ledg_ Entry].[Posting Date])>=2017
```

The problem is I get the value "Valor pendente" equals to "1838" instead of "10" like the image below.

[image]

I follow this example i found online to create my sql query..

```
Sum("Detailed Cust. Ledg. Entry"."Amount (LCY)" WHERE (Cust. Ledger Entry No.=FIELD(Entry No.),Entry Type=FILTER(Initial Entry),Posting Date=FIELD(Date Filter)))

Select Sum([Amount (LCY)] FROM [Detailed Cust. Ledg. Entry]
INNER JOIN
[Cust. Ledg. Entry]
ON
[Detailed Cust. Ledg. Entry].[Entry No.] = [Cust. Ledg. Entry].[Entry No.]
WHERE
[Detailed Cust. Ledg. Entry].[Entry Type] = "Initial Entry"
```

My full query is here below:

```
select 'E18375' as Empresa, [E18375$Detailed Vendor Ledg_ Entry].[Posting Date],
[E18375$Detailed Vendor Ledg_ Entry].[Document No_], 
[E18375$Detailed Vendor Ledg_ Entry].[Vendor No_], 
[E18375$Detailed Vendor Ledg_ Entry].Amount, (Select Sum([Amount (LCY)])
FROM [E18375$Detailed Vendor Ledg_ Entry]
INNER JOIN [E18375$Vendor Ledger Entry] ON [E18375$Detailed Vendor Ledg_ Entry].[Vendor Ledger Entry No_] = [E18375$Vendor Ledger Entry].[Entry No_] 
WHERE [E18375$Detailed Vendor Ledg_ Entry].[Excluded from calculation]=0 
AND [E18375$Detailed Vendor Ledg_ Entry].[Amount]>0) as 'Valor pendente'
from [E18375$Vendor Ledger Entry] inner join [E18375$Detailed Vendor Ledg_ Entry] on [E18375$Detailed Vendor Ledg_ Entry].[Vendor Ledger Entry No_]=[E18375$Vendor Ledger Entry] .[Entry No_] 
where [E18375$Vendor Ledger Entry].[Open]=1 and [E18375$Detailed Vendor Ledg_ Entry].[Document No_]='1707NC006'
group by [E18375$Detailed Vendor Ledg_ Entry].[Posting Date], [E18375$Detailed Vendor Ledg_ Entry].[Document No_],
 [E18375$Detailed Vendor Ledg_ Entry].[Vendor No_], [E18375$Detailed Vendor Ledg_ Entry].[Vendor Ledger Entry No_], 
[E18375$Detailed Vendor Ledg_ Entry].[Amount]
having sum([E18375$Detailed Vendor Ledg_ Entry].[Amount])>0
```

Comment: I've updated my answer

Comment: Your embedded select is wrong. Its not correlated with anything so you are getting the full sum of the table. Its hard to work out what you are trying to do. That final Having clause does not refer to the same table as the one nested in the [Valor pendente] column

Comment: Also, please add table aliases as my eyes glazed over trying to work out the difference between the 4 very long and only slightly different table names.

Comment: I want to group by document number the vendor Amount remaining to pay..

Answer (score 0):

So it seems you only have 2 tables you're interested in:

[E18375$Detailed Vendor Ledg_ Entry]
[E18375$Vendor Ledger Entry]

It looks like you're missing [Entry Type] = "Initial Entry" from your query:

```
Select Sum([E18375$Detailed Vendor Ledg_ Entry].[Amount]) as 'Valor pendente'
FROM [E18375$Detailed Vendor Ledg_ Entry]
INNER JOIN [E18375$Vendor Ledger Entry] ON [E18375$Detailed Vendor Ledg_ Entry].[Entry No_] = [E18375$Vendor Ledger Entry].[Entry No_]
WHERE [E18375$Detailed Vendor Ledg_ Entry].[Excluded from calculation] = 0
AND [E18375$Detailed Vendor Ledg_ Entry].[Entry Type] = "Initial Entry";
```

I'm going to guess that one of your tables has one record in it and the other has lots of records, and it's the filtering that's not working correctly.

Comment: Does the [E18375$Detailed Vendor Ledg_ Entry] table contain the [Entry Type] field? If so, you'll want to filter by that too. Just like in my example code.

Comment: What does the 'Valor pendente' query return when you run it by itself, does it give you the correct value?

Comment: What does this return:

 SELECT dvel.[Amount]
 FROM [E18375$Detailed Vendor Ledg_ Entry] dvel
 WHERE dvel.[Entry No_] IN
  (
  SELECT [Entry No_]
  FROM [E18375$Vendor Ledger Entry]
  WHERE [Document No_]='1707NC006'
  )
 AND dvel.[Excluded from calculation] = 0;

Comment: Nothing, can we talk in chat @Jim Jimson?

Comment: OK we talk here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180210/discussion-between-jim-jimson-and-catia-matos).

Answer (score 0):

I'm going out on a limb here, as the query as written doesn't make much sense. But I think you want to get the detail lines for each row, and the total for the vendor.

This will do it:

```
select 'E18375' as Empresa, 
L4.[Posting Date], 
L4.[Document No_], 
L4.[Vendor No_], 
L4.Amount, 
VT as 'Valor pendente' 
from [E18375$Vendor Ledger Entry] L3
inner join [E18375$Detailed Vendor Ledg_ Entry] L4 on L4.[Vendor Ledger Entry No_]=L3.[Entry No_] 
join (
    Select [Vendor No_], Sum([Amount (LCY)]) as VT
    FROM [E18375$Detailed Vendor Ledg_ Entry] L1
    INNER JOIN [E18375$Vendor Ledger Entry] L2 ON L1.[Entry No_] = L2.[Entry No_] 
    WHERE L1.[Excluded from calculation]=0 AND L1.[Amount]>0
    group by [Vendor No_]
    ) VendorTotal on VendorTotal.[Vendor No_]=L4.[Vendor No_]
where L3.[Open]=1 and L4.[Document No_]='1707NC006'
and VT>0
```

Comment: It raises error in the Vendor No_ column (Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 21
The multi-part identifier "L4.Vendor No_" could not be bound.)

Comment: I must have missed a space, underscore or something. L4 refers to [E18375$Detailed Vendor Ledg_ Entry]. Does [E18375$Detailed Vendor Ledg_ Entry].Vendor No_ exist?

Comment: "vendor No." exists in table "E18375$Detailed Vendor Ledg_ Entry"

Comment: Please just check the field names. Your question seems to flip between `[Entry No_]` and `[Entry No.]` It sounds like from your error that it should be the version that end in a full stop ratherthan an underscore. If so, update what I wrote to match. Your "Full query" in your question uses underscores which is what I based my answer on.

Comment: @CátiaMatos I think you're confusing "question" and "answer". You've updated your question. No big deal, just a bit confusing.

Comment: I've updated because I thought I need to clarify my question